# Пустой EditText

Tags: java, android

Хочу запретить посылать пустой текст, но даже кода поле заполнено, он cнова показывает error text.

```
public class elaqemesage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
int etN;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qebul);
 textsoname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textsoname);


public void onClick(View v) {
        if (textsoname.getText().length() == 0) etN = 0;

        if ((etN == 0)){
            textsoname.setError("Заполните Пустое Поле");
        } else {
            mymetho();
        }
}
```

Comment: Откуда взялась переменная `textsoname`?

Comment: прописана в oncreate

Comment: Чему равен "etN"  до этой строки:   "if (textsoname.getText().length() == 0) etN = 0;"

Comment: int etN; пиропсиан

Comment: Я в ответе привел варианты решения

Comment: буду пробыать))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю проблема в том что etN, всегда 0.

Попробуй так:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (textsoname.getText().length() == 0){
            textsoname.setError("Заполните Пустое Поле");
        } else {
            mymetho();
        }
}
```

или

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
            if (textsoname.getText().length() == 0) etN = 0;

            if ((etN == 0)){
            etN = 1;
                textsoname.setError("Заполните Пустое Поле");
            } else {
                mymetho();
            }
    }
```

Comment: ща попробую  посмотрим)

Comment: Конечно первый вариант. Второй как бы намекает, что в этом коде не обошлось без индуса - переменная etN совершенно неуместна.

Comment: ну это на всякий случай, если ТС убрал часть кода или  etN  еще где-то используется.